# How to execute curve_fit(func,x,y) with multiple input parameters in python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I want to use curve_fit in python with 8 independet parameters (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)

My raw data from the experiment ist:

[image]

The global function is the normal distribution.

Behind mu and sigma there is an individual model equation:

mu(a,b,c,d,oc1,oc2,oc3)= a * b^oc1 * c^oc2 * d^oc3

sigma(e,f,g,h,oc1,oc2,oc3) = e * f^oc1 * g^oc2 * h^oc3

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 
import numpy as np

def normalmodel(x, mu, sigma, oc1, oc2, oc3, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h):

mu = a * b^oc1 * c^oc2 * d^oc3
sigma = e * f^oc1 * g^oc2 * h^oc3


   #normal distribution definition
    coefficient = 1 / math.sqrt(2 * math.pi * sigma**2)
    exponent = - (x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)

    return coefficient * math.exp(exponent)

xdata = np.column_stack((oc1, oc2, oc3))
ydata = np.column_stack((mean, std))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(normalmodel, xdata, ydata)
```

What is the correct input into curve_fit function to run the optimization?

Or is there a smoother way?

Comment: You have those 7 lines of data to fit 8 values? ...or is there more?

Answer (score 1):

The following runs, but the fits are very poor because of your model.

```py
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize

with StringIO(
'''test, mean,        std, oc1,   oc2, oc3
1, 0.97713742, 0.26694917,  95, 45.00,   0
2, 0.12184188, 0.44894088,  80, 47.50,   0
3, 0.58538510, 0.24009228,  80, 30.00,   1
4, 0.51518946, 0.68956235,  90, 30.00,   1
5, 0.90588498, 0.24522218,  95, 30.00,   1
6, 0.53294345, 0.28555743,  95, 45.00,   1
7, 0.64574645, 0.61925369,  95, 20.00,   1''') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, skipinitialspace=True, index_col='test')


def prod_power(oc: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float, c: float, d: float) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    mu(a,b,c,d,oc1,oc2,oc3)= a * b^oc1 * c^oc2 * d^oc3
    sigma(e,f,g,h,oc1,oc2,oc3) = e * f^oc1 * g^oc2 * h^oc3
    """
    return a*((b, c, d)**oc).prod(axis=1)


oc = df[['oc1', 'oc2', 'oc3']].values
abcd, *_ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(
    f=prod_power, xdata=oc, ydata=df['mean'], p0=(1, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99))
efgh, *_ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(
    f=prod_power, xdata=oc, ydata=df['std'], p0=(1, 0.99, 0.99, 0.99))

print('abcd =', abcd)
print('mu ~', prod_power(oc, *abcd))
print('efgh =', efgh)
print('sigma ~', prod_power(oc, *efgh))
```

```
abcd = [0.00432871 1.06208019 0.991149   0.72510257]
mu ~ [0.88624964 0.35119134 0.29751689 0.54335632 0.73429619 0.64262189
 0.8025679 ]
efgh = [1.77403653 0.99936209 0.96690784 0.68162547]
sigma ~ [0.36725183 0.34086593 0.41868799 0.41602479 0.41469956 0.2503282
 0.58060767]
```

Comment: Thanks @reinderien. What if i change the model to this equation: return np.exp(a) * (np.exp(b*oc1)) * (np.exp(c*oc2)) * (np.exp(d*oc3))? How can i assign the correct oc values correctly?

Comment: @newtopy I consider that out of scope for this question. If you can't figure it out, post a new question